# Make Chessboard stack Image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, erdas-imagine, envi, digital-image-processing

I am learning some literature of works and came across a beautiful representation of image in chessboard form.  That misaligned  is not my current concern. We are group of bachelor students and are trying mostly in 'Python' to achieve such representation of stack of images.

We tried dicing image and stack/overlay but cannot generate output like this one. Anyone having idea how to do this? I am asking for other image processing software too. **link is provided **

[image]

**Important Note**
We are now trying for blending the two images via tiles. Let us see if we can solve this. Anybody with idea to our problem Please help.

Comment: Is that link what you want to achieve, or what you've got?  What have you actually done, and how?  In what way is it not what you want?  Please **[edit]** your question to add more detail about what you've tried and what happens when you try it.  You've tagged ArcGIS Desktop, python, erdas-imagine, and envi - which one are you using?

Comment: Apart from what @Midavalo suggested, you can add pictures here by properly referencing since the original location might be altered in the future therefore people would not find it. Also what do these picture try to tell? All i can see the same picture shown three times highlighting the same misaligned road sections whereas the buildings surrounding do not match.

Comment: @Midavalo Sir, the image is what I want to achieve. The concern that software were mentioned so that I get an understanding how it could be done.We are group of bachelor students and are trying mostly in 'Python'.

Comment: @Anvesh if you are doing this in python please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the code you have tried and details of what happens when you try it. Include images of the output result also. You need to include much more information as all you've told us is that you can't generate it. Do you get an image? Do you get any output at all? In what way is it not what you want? Please put all this info into your question.

Comment: @Midavalo Sorry sir, at this moment we can not share here. Regarding output as Image, yes we see both image displayed over another but we are now playing with Transparency and swipe only to do this.

Comment: It's impossible for us to help if we don't know what's wrong or how you're trying to do it. GIS.SE is not a coding service. We're happy to try to help solve a problem, but at the moment we don't know what that problem is.

Comment: @Midavalo I think right now we require an idea on how such representation can be achieved, once we are able to do it. I will definitely post the code and results. kindly uphold this question so that others might  help.

Comment: Please see my comment above  - we can't help solve your problem as we don't know what you've tried or what the problem is.